# Удаление и добавление элементов в массив

Tags: java

Как можно добавить элемент в маccив таким образом что бы он был поверх всего массива ? 
Пример: `2 4 6 -> 8 2 4 6` 
И как удалить элемент массива ? 
Пример: `8 2 4 6 -> 8 2 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вас интересуют конкретно обычные массивы, самые простые и быстрые способы выглядят так:

Добавляем элемент в начало:

```
public int[] addToHead(int value, int[] source) {
    int[] result = new int[source.length + 1];
    result[0] = value;
    System.arraycopy(source, 0, result, 1, source.length);
    return result;
}
```

Удаляем последний элемент:

```
public int[] removeLast(int[] source) {
    int[] result = new int[source.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(source, 0, result, 0, source.length - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Можно использовать всякие Queue, или придумать способ в два раза длиннее с использованием Stream API, но проще и быстрее реализации, чем я описал выше, я не думаю, что получится найти.

В обоих случаях создаются новые массивы, но это всё равно быстрее работы обёрток и списков, которые под капотом делают тоже самое.

---

В комментариях вы спросили насчёт реализации с циклами:

```
public static int[] addToHead(int value, int[] source) {
    int[] result = new int[source.length + 1];
    result[0] = value;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        result[i + 1] = source[i];
    }
    return result;
}

public static int[] removeLast(int[] source) {
    int[] result = new int[source.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length - 1; i++) {
        result[i] = source[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: А если такие способы которые можно легко реализовать в цикле ? 
Я просто не совсем представляю как я могу представить это все в цикле.

Comment: @Иоанн дополнил ответ вариантами с циклами.

Comment: уже готовые конструкции есть. очереди!!!

Comment: @Санаев да, отлично, а ещё есть commons-lang, guava, и много чего ещё. Давайте для тривиальнейшей задачи использовать то, в чём нет смысла. Тем более очереди я упомянул в ответе.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin нет смысла в  готовой очереди? не понимаю вас

Comment: @Санаев автор не просил найти ему структуру в языке, которая тоже умеет делать что-то подобное. Его вопрос состоял в том, как сделать определённые примитивнейшие действия над массивом. Вы же пытаетесь (не в первом вопросе) "блеснуть" примитивнейшими знаниями там, где в них нет нужды. Использовать излишние структуры вроде очереди там, где это не нужно и где об этом не просят. Код, где можно решить проблему одной строчкой кода, переписывать полностью костыли с использованием Stream API, давая такой ответ автору, который с работой boolean в языке не разобрался ещё. Подумайте над целесообразностью

Comment: @PeterSamokhin даже спорить с вами не хочу.

Comment: @Санаев не хотите, но упорно пытаетесь, хотя сайт не для этого. Но совет примите: если вы увидели что-то, смутно подходящее под ваше описание, будь то новая технология, какой-то другой тип списка и т. п. — не стоит сразу бросаться за использование, и ещё и другим предлагать. Если стоит конкретный вопрос, иногда бывает, что автор неправильно формулирует и очевидно, что хочет он другого результата, — но не в ситуации, подобной текущему вопросу.